# Does hiking improve the fitness of the knee?

Tags: knees, knee-pain, soreness

I recently went on a few hikes for the first time in a while and the descent caused some severe knee pain. I did some research and found that "Hikers knee" is a [common first time hiking experience](https://arizonapain.com/knee-pain-after-hiking/).

Supposedly, this is caused by:

> inflammation of a small fluid-filled sac called a bursa. These sacs reduce friction and cushion the pressure points between your bones and the tendons, muscles, and skin near your joints. When they become inflamed, they can lead to pain.

So my question is; Do the *Bursa* eventually adapt to increased pressure/friction on the knees in people that hike often? Or, is there a technique for descending a mountain that is less rough on the knees?

Answer (score 2):

#### [The most common causes of bursitis are overuse and acute injury](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/conditions-and-diseases/bursitis?amp=true).

Since you don’t describe any sort of acute trauma to the knee that could lead to bursitis, overuse is the obvious culprit. Your body adapts to the stress you put it under, but too much too soon can lead to overuse conditions, such as bursitis.

If you develop bursitis from hiking, this is likely indicating that *the dose of hiking is too great for your current level of fitness*. The obvious solution then is to keep training, but reduce the intensity, allow your body to adapt to the stress you put it through, and slowly increase the dose as your level of fitness improves.

Answer (score 0):

To answer about the technique, look into hiking or trekking poles. While you see people use them for ascent, they can play an important role on the descent.

As you step down, you put that momentum and weight of your body on your knees.

With trekking poles, you extend them and allow them to find solid ground and your arms to bear some of the weight your knees were taking.

Here is an [article](https://www.cooperinstitute.org/2011/02/do-trekking-poles-make-a-difference/) (Cooper Institute) that has references specific studies regarding these poles minimizing impact and injury.